# How can I turn off anti-aliasing for the text editor in Flash Builder on the Mac?

Tags: macos, flash, anti-aliasing, flexbuilder

Is it possible to turn off anti-aliasing for the text editor in Flash Builder on the Mac?

For Flex Builder I was able to do this via the terminal using the following

```
defaults write com.adobe.flexbuilder AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20 
defaults write com.adobe.flexbuilder AppleSmoothFixedFontsSizeThreshold 20
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736856/default-font-in-eclipse-on-osx-is-terrible-and-blurred) has the answer:

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 10
```